# How to avoid type conversion in flex from string to number?

Tags: apache-flex, string, actionscript, numbers

I am returning 12345678910111213171819 from java to flex, with in xml tags using http serivce. The result format is object.

but when I display the text it automatically converted or treated as number
so it displays like 1.234567891011121317181 x e^21 ....

How to avoid this?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Sankara narayanan Ekambaranathan.

Comment: Does the service define the property as an `object` type or `string` type? If its object, you should sipmly beable to cast it to a string if thats what you want.

Comment: Nate Bross,
By default the resultformat of our service is 'object' only.
we tried '.toString()'.But it does not work. :(

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply coerce it with String()?

```
var returnedObject:String = String(123463457695);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest solution is just a little workaround to the issue:

Instead of sending the open data like 
12345678910111213171819

Convert the data into Base 64 Encoding While transmitting
MTIzNDU2Nzg5MTAxMTEyMTMxNzE4MTk=

In Flex Convert back the data using the standard Base 64 Decoder provided with flex
to convert it back into String instead of number format during XML parsing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on one of my projects.

After a lot of googling and investigation I fixed it by changing result format to XML and manually parsing the XML with explicit type conversions.

Another (actually, more correct) way is to define a schema for the response and somehow apply it to the XML decoder but I haven't found an easy way to do it.